# running a pillow alpha_composite on two files results in a huge huge file

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have two files I open via these lines:

```
image0 = Image.open(infile0).convert("RGBA")
image1 = Image.open(infile1).convert("RGBA").resize(image0.size)
```

image0 is a 8MB jpg.
image1 is a tiny 4.3K file that is an overlay to the first one, so it is resized to be the same size as image0.

After I then run the alpha_composite command:

```
result = Image.alpha_composite(image0, image1)
result.save(outfile)
```

Where outfile ends up being a huge 23-43MB PNG file.  This seems way to large (I also do this once a minute and create time lapses using FFMPEG which seem to take too long because of the large size of the input files).  I want the file to be as detailed as possible, I would like it to be a tad smaller and more manageable in size.
I had some success using this command:

```
result2 = result.resize((round(result.size[0]*0.20), round(result.size[1]*0.20)))
```

then doing a result2.save(thumbnail_path), though that file size does seem the quality suffered some, so not sure if I am doing it correctly or if there is a better way in Pillow?

Comment: Yes, PNG files are going to be much larger than JPEG, because they're not lossy.  That's normal and expected.

Comment: I agree, and not lossy is def what I was looking for, just seemed like a bit much.  I guess I can deal with that large size somehow.  It mostly comes into play in the time it takes to create a movie with FFMPEG which I am guessing because the size is so large of each file.  Is that resize method a generally accepted one to get decent quality?

Comment: Your `resize` does not specify a method, I don't remember what the default is. There are existing questions that examine it.

Comment: Remember also that video files use lossy compression, so using it for the intermediate files may not be as bad as you think.

Comment: ty I will hunt around more and do some tests, feels like I am not totally barking up the right tree with this.  It seems like if my hardware puts out only JPG there is no point in going to PNG later I would suspect.